# json parsing error: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: php, android, json, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to make a simple chat application with Google Cloud Messaging. I keep get error message 'json parsing error: Value < br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject' while trying to send a message. Here is the method that causes the problem

```
private void sendMessage() {
    final String message = this.inputMessage.getText().toString().trim();

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(message)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter a message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    String endPoint = EndPoints.CHAT_ROOM_MESSAGE.replace("_ID_", chatRoomId);

    Log.e(TAG, "endpoint: " + endPoint);

    this.inputMessage.setText("");

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            endPoint, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.e(TAG, "response: " + response);

            try {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);

                // check for error
                if (obj.getBoolean("error") == false) {
                    JSONObject commentObj = obj.getJSONObject("message");

                    String commentId = commentObj.getString("message_id");
                    String commentText = commentObj.getString("message");
                    String createdAt = commentObj.getString("created_at");

                    JSONObject userObj = obj.getJSONObject("user");
                    String userId = userObj.getString("user_id");
                    String userName = userObj.getString("name");
                    User user = new User(userId, userName, null);

                    Message message = new Message();
                    message.setId(commentId);
                    message.setMessage(commentText);
                    message.setCreatedAt(createdAt);
                    message.setUser(user);

                    messageArrayList.add(message);

                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    if (mAdapter.getItemCount() > 1) {
                        // scrolling to bottom of the recycler view
                        recyclerView.getLayoutManager().smoothScrollToPosition(recyclerView, null, mAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);
                    }

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "json parse error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
            Log.e(TAG, "Volley error: " + error.getMessage() + ", code: " + networkResponse);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Volley error: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            inputMessage.setText(message);
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("user_id", MyApplication.getInstance().getPrefManager().getUser().getId());
            params.put("message", message);

            Log.e(TAG, "Params: " + params.toString());

            return params;
        };
    };


    // disabling retry policy so that it won't make
    // multiple http calls
    int socketTimeout = 0;
    RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);

    strReq.setRetryPolicy(policy);

    //Adding request to request queue
    MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq);
}
```

I got this error message

```
06-08 17:37:40.491 8022-8022/com.ciangproduction.cp.gcmsample E/ChatRoomActivity: response: <br />
                                                                              <font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-uncaught-exception' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
                                                                              <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Cannot create LogWriter. Invalid resource handle.' in E:\wamp64\www\gcm_chat\libs\Slim\LogWriter.php on line <i>60</i></th></tr>
                                                                              <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> InvalidArgumentException: Cannot create LogWriter. Invalid resource handle. in E:\wamp64\www\gcm_chat\libs\Slim\LogWriter.php on line <i>60</i></th></tr>
                                                                              <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
                                                                              <tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
                                                                              <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0012</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>354400</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='E:\wamp64\www\gcm_chat\v1\index.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\index.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
                                                                              <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>2</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0184</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>1072048</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Slim\Slim->run(  )</td><td title='E:\wamp64\www\gcm_chat\v1\index.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\index.php<b>:</b>453</td></tr>
                                                                              <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>3</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0196</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>1096864</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Slim\Middleware\PrettyExceptions->call(  )</td><td title='E:\wamp64\www\gcm_chat\libs\Slim\Slim.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\Slim.php<b>:</b>1254</td></tr>
                                                                              <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>4</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.2351</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>1371432</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Slim\Slim->getLog(  )</td><td title='E:\wamp64\www\gcm_chat\libs\Slim\Middleware\PrettyExceptions.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\PrettyExceptions.php<b>:</b>69</td></tr>
                                                                              <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>5</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.2351</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>1371632</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Slim\Slim->__get(  )</td><td title='E:\wamp64\www\gcm_chat\libs\Slim\Middleware\PrettyExceptions.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\PrettyExceptions.php<b>:</b>388</td></tr>
                                                                              <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>6</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.2351</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>1371632</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Slim\Helper\Set->offsetGet(  )</td><td title='E:\wamp64\www\gcm_chat\libs\Slim\Middleware\PrettyExceptions.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\PrettyExceptions.php<b>:</b>226</td></tr>
                                                                              <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>7</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.2351</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>1371632</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Slim\Helper\Set->get(  )</td><td title='E:\wamp64\www\gcm_chat\libs\Slim\Helper\Set.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\Set.php<b>:</b>185</td></tr>
                                                                              <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>8</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.2352</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>1371760</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Slim\Helper\Set->Slim\Helper\{closure}(  )</td><td title='E:\wamp64\www\gcm_chat\libs\Slim\Helper\Set.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\Set.php<b>:</b>88</td></tr>
                                                                              <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>9</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.2352</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>1371864</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Slim\Slim->Slim\{closure}(  )</td><td title='E:\wamp64\www\gcm_chat\libs\Slim\Helper\Set.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\Set.php<b>:</b>228</td></tr>
                                                                              <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>10</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.2352</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>1372088</td><t
06-08 17:37:40.491 8022-8022/com.ciangproduction.cp.gcmsample E/ChatRoomActivity: json parsing error: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

here is the LogWriter.php

```
<?php
class LogWriter
{
    /**
     * @var resource
     */
    protected $resource;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param  resource                  $resource
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException If invalid resource
     */
public function __construct($resource)
{
    if (!is_resource($resource)) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Cannot create LogWriter. Invalid resource handle.');
    }
    $this->resource = $resource;
}

/**
 * Write message
 * @param  mixed     $message
 * @param  int       $level
 * @return int|bool
 */
public function write($message, $level = null)
{
    return fwrite($this->resource, (string) $message . PHP_EOL);
}
}
```

the method is executed when I send message trough this app. Then it shows the error. Please help! Thank you

Comment: That response is not in JSON format.

Comment: Error in LogWriter.php on line 60.

Comment: share this file code -> E:\wamp64\www\gcm_chat\libs\Slim\LogWriter.php

Comment: The request you sent has triggered a bug in the PHP code on the server side.  That has cause the server to send an HTML error message rather than a JSON response.  Solution: read the HTML error message and fix the server side bug.

Comment: Thank you for your reply earthw0rmjim, but I don't really understand about that. I'm new in android.

Comment: @Omi I have updated the code. Please check it out. By the way, thank you for replying.

Comment: @StephenC Actually I don't really understand php language. I got this whole code from here http://www.androidhive.info/2016/02/android-push-notifications-using-gcm-php-mysql-realtime-chat-app-part-1/

Comment: You are unlikely to get help with debugging PHP if you tag your questions "java".